# Android app does not connect to firebase analytics

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I tried adding firebase to my application but it didn't work at all. I successfully connected my application with firebase by using Tools -> Firebase in android studio and added the dependencies.

[image]

It connected successfully but whatever I try, the firebase console says it's still waiting for my app to communicate with their servers (I waited one night by now).

[image]

When I start the application, the logcat doesn't say anything about firebase

[image]

I did exactly the same steps with a newly created (empty) application and it worked without problems.

I tried to uninstall and reinstall the app again, I cleared the cache in android studio, rebuilded the project, resynced it with gradle. Nothing worked.

This is the gradle file in my app module: https://pastebin.com/gKHa68ii

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.2.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.5.0'
```

This is my other gradle file: https://pastebin.com/Y3bCrHDM

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.2.0'
```

Comment: where did you add google-service.json file?

Comment: It's in /app https://imgur.com/a/2UBslid

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

at the of your App module gradlew file

Comment: I have this line at the beginning of my gradle file.
I moved the line `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` to the end of the file, it didn't make a difference though